# Nginx always returning a 404 for non index pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I was able to deploy a site (http://taiga.market) and it appears that Nginx works on the index page. If you click a link to go to another page (http://taiga.market/login) Nginx responds with a 404. It does this for every page except the index and I have no idea why.

I thought it was SSL, but it turns out that non-protected pages also do not render.

I'm not really sure what's happening. The nginx configuration is as so:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name taiga.market;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/deploy/taiga/current/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

There was nothing logged in production.log or nginx's error.log, but there was information inside of the access.log:

```
24.85.70.29 - - [15/Mar/2015:01:51:01 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1613 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36"
24.85.70.29 - - [15/Mar/2015:01:51:04 -0400] "GET /user/spree_user/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 404 715 "http://taiga.market/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36"
24.85.70.29 - - [15/Mar/2015:01:51:04 -0400] "GET /user/spree_user/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 404 715 "http://taiga.market/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Remove `index` directive, `location /` location and all error handlers. Then restart nginx and try to reproduce problem.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: for correct work of rails `passenger` remove following lines:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```